# Using HTML5, CSS3, and Javascript for Windows Phone 8.1 App Development

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows-phone-8

I have been working for web design and some development for almost three years and quite familiar with HTML5, CSS3, an robust Javascript as JQuery.

Now I want to delve into Windows Phone application development since I heard it requires HTML5, CSS3, and Javascript as far as I can understand the development process will be as same as we develop website separate individual files like index.html (for html) .css (for css) .js (for javascript) in a folder.

Do I need other skills and languages or I am on the right path?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking on the official microsoft site.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677133.aspx

It really depends on what you want to include in your app. In my opinion is worth looking at C and C++ as it will help you develop more features and have this native mobile feel. If you want to be on the safe side, you can still use html5, css3 and js. you should take a look at Client-side JScript.

Comment: as far as I can understand after getting your suggestion is that if we need complex business applications then we should know C and C++ and if we are developing a light weight application with no usage of business functions such as mathematical logics or stuff like that we can go for html5, css3, and javascript. Is that right?

Comment: If you want get all of the phone features e.g camera etc, you would have to use the native language. If you are more confident in using js then you have to create a hybrid app. in order to do that, you would need to use a framework such as phonegap or titanium sdk. The only problem is that you won't get the native feel you would have in a native app.

Comment: So you mean we don't access hardware features with the technologies above, and we have to use native language if our application has to access device hardware features right?

Comment: Exactly. However, there are workarounds but that is the main disadvantage so far of HTML5 as it relies on a browser and cannot communicate directly to the phone.

Comment: Yes it is a serious drawback of HTML5, so when we develop apps in html5 for windows phone it uses the browser engine or something to run our app on the phone?

Comment: Yes it requires a browser engine in order to run or a browser wrapper like phonegap.

Comment: Thank you pal, it was a nice and good conversation with you. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develop with only HTML5, CSS and JavaScript, you will have to use a framework, it's like a bridge between HTML5/CSS/JS and the platform (Windows SDK, Android SDK, iOS).

You can start with [Adobe's Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/), and if you feel comfortable you can delve into the patform specific techniques instead of just the framework.

Comment: thanks for specifying the technologies and their platforms. I use visual studio for coding and sometimes Adobe's Bracket do I still need the Adobe's Phonegap? Also mention the name of the framework you are talking about for connecting html5, css3, and js to windows phones app development. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another option is WinJS, but if you learn a little bit of C# and get familiar with XAML I think you are going to be able to develop and maintain apps easier.